# Getting Json from Url from inside a service

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I got a problem with my function that doesn't work from a service.

Before I give you more details on the problem let me explain how It works.  After clicking on a submit button, I call my function ''sendItineraryRequestUrl()'' this function will Get a Json from an URL then I pass that Json object to the function ''drawItineraryOnMap(jsonItineraryResponse: any)''  witch draws the itinerary on a Map.

CASE1 :
in the first case my code works I was able to get the JSON Object and then draw the itinerary on the map.
inside my component class  :

```
sendItineraryRequestUrl() {
var getJSONResponse = (url: any, callback: any) => {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', url, true);
  xhr.responseType = 'json';
  xhr.onload = () => {
    var status = xhr.status;
    if (status === 200) {
      callback(null, xhr.response);
    } else {
      callback(status);
    }
  };
  xhr.send();
};


getJSONResponse('MYSERVERURL',
  (err: any, jsonData: any) => {
    if (err !== null) {
      alert('Something went wrong: ' + err);
    } else {
      this.drawItineraryOnMap(jsonData, this.routeGroup);
    }
  });
}
drawItineraryOnMap(jsonItineraryResponse: any, layerGroup: any) {
//... my drawing function code
}
```

CASE2: In the case I created an itierary-request.service.ts and inside it i putted my sendItineraryRequestUrl() and renamed it to fetchItineraryResponse() with some changes :
In this case my itineraryRequestResponse is always undefined

Inside my service class :

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class ItineraryRequestService {
itineraryRequestResponse: any;

fetchItineraryResponse() : any {
let getJSONResponse = (url: any, callback: any) => {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', url, true);
  xhr.responseType = 'json';
  xhr.onload = () => {
    var status = xhr.status;
    if (status === 200) {
      callback(null, xhr.response);
    } else {
      callback(status);
    }
  };
  xhr.send();
 };

 getJSONResponse('MY SERVER URL',
  (err: any, jsonData: any) => {
    if (err !== null) {
      alert('Something went wrong: ' + err);
    } else {
     this.itineraryRequestResponse = jsonData;
    }
  });
  return this.itineraryRequestResponse;

 }
}
```

and inside my component class :

```
constructor(private geoCodingService: GeoCodingService,
          private polylineDecodingService: PolylineDecodingService,
          private itineraryRequestService: ItineraryRequestService) {}

sendItineraryRequestUrl() {
  let jsonData = this.itineraryRequestService.fetchItineraryResponse();
  this.drawItineraryOnMap(jsonData, this.routeGroup);
}

drawItineraryOnMap(jsonItineraryResponse: any, layerGroup: any) {
//... my drawing function code
}
```

I did't forget to add my service in my component providers or import my service. 
I am sure the problem comes from the Json function.

Thank you guys in advance for any help you can give me !

Comment: Check the context in your callback inside `getJSONResponse()` (`console.log(this)`). You might have to call calback with `callback.apply(this, null, xhr.response)`

Comment: I changed callback(null, xhr.response); with callback.apply(this, null, xhr.response); I got an error : Something went wrong: undefined

Comment: Should be `callback.apply(this, [null, xhr.response])`, my bad (: [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply#Syntax)

Comment: for the console.log(this) :ItineraryRequestService {urlProtocol: "http://", otpServerAdress: "XX.XXX.XX.XX", otpServerPort: "8080", formatedItineraryTime: "&time=13%3A24", itineraryRequestResponse: Object}

Comment: It's working but not on the first call ^^ on the second click it works

Comment: in the debug mod he get's inside the if (status === 200) {} later after going inside the draw function :X how is it possible ?

Comment: Not sure I follow anymore (: I try not to use callbacks since I discovered rxjs; Expression *callback hell* speaks for itself :P

Comment: Why not just use angular's `Http` service?

Comment: I would love to use angular's Http service but I don't know how, I just started learning angular ^^

Comment: Take a look at the [tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html) on official docs site. Notice that Http is last chapter in the tutorial, so if you're just starting consider starting from chapter 1 (;

Comment: problem solved I used Angular 2 http service 
    sendItineraryRequestUrl() {
     this.itineraryRequestService.get(this.planRequest)
      .subscribe(plan => this.drawOnMap(plan, this.routeGroup),
        error => console.error(error));
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using angular 2 http service to solve the problem.
thank you Sasxa for the help !

I can give the full modifications if someone need them.

```
sendItineraryRequestUrl() {
 this.itineraryRequestService.get(this.planRequest)
  .subscribe(plan => this.drawOnMap(plan, this.routeGroup),
    error => console.error(error));
}
```